# Extract variables into template with global scope

Tags: php

I want to extract all variables assigned in my controller into my template using the extract() function. An simple example is this:

```
  private function render() {
        extract($this->controller_vars);
        require_once("layout.php");
  }
```

The problem is that within my layout.php I am making calls to other methods which "includes" files but more importantly displays the correct action/view within the layout.

```
  // This method is called where I want to display the "content" page:
  public function display_action() {
        require_once("selected_action.php");
  }
```

So I effectively have access to the extracted variables inside of layout.php, but my view/actions don't because they are included through a method in the same controller.

Is there a workaround where I can give the extracted variables global access or perhaps another solution for my problem?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

The code above is 2 "watered down" versions of the methods in my view class

```
  class views {

        private function render() {
              extract($this->controller_vars);
              require_once("layout.php");
        }


        public function display_action() {
              require_once("selected_action.php");
        }

  }
```

In the layout.php file I would then make a call  such as:

```
  <div id="content_area">
        $this->display_action();
  </div>
```

**MORE MORE MORE**

I do have access to these variables at the moment by an array property in my view class called $this->controller_vars, so if I assigned a list of users it would be stored in $this->controller_vars['users']; I am just looking for a way to extract it so that I can have access to them with a simple $users as appose to $this->controller_vars['users']

Comment: Is this OpenCart's code?

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is not a direct answer, but you might want to consider 'going' Object Oriented with this. If you make the Controllers and Actions objects, they can still be included/required more or less the same way (using an [autoloader](http://php.net/autoload)), and you can pass variables to them via e.g. the constructor.

Something like this:

```
Class Layout {
    public function processAction() {
        $class = 'Action' . $selected_action;
        $Controller = new $class( $this->controller_vars );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it is OOP, I just pasted the specific methods I use to minimize the size of the question, all these methods are located in my views class

Comment: Ah right, I just noticed the visibility keywords. In that case, it will only be easier for you to implement this I think.

Comment: At this point of time I am able to gain access to the variables by doing $this->controller_vars['assigned_variable']; but I'm just looking for an easier way to not have to right that but rather just have it as $assigned_variable (say I got an array of users from the db, it appears easier to do print_r($users); as appose to print_r($this->controller_vars['users']);

Comment: Well, your code looks like a kinda funky mix between OO and procedural :) You started off with an object, but why did you go back to oldskool including code later on in the methods?

Comment: It's not as much including code but more including HTML. My layout.php contains all of the HTML for the layout. In my views class I have a method called view_include() which I use to include snippets of HTML code (such as the header, footer etc). The method would then include the file using classic include or require but already contains the location to the file (so as appose to include(INCLUDES_DIR."filename.php"); I just do $this->view_include("filename.php"); . The same goes for the display_action() which includes the action into the layout